# Does the code snippet qualify as a function-statement, function-expression and function-expression-statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some code from [EcmaScript.NET](http://code.google.com/p/ecmascript-net/) and in particular, I'm looking at the definitions in [FunctionNode.cs](http://code.google.com/p/ecmascript-net/source/browse/trunk/EcmaScript.NET/FunctionNode.cs). They've provided a relatively descriptive comment above the definitions, but I'm not sure what would my example below qualify as:

```
/// <summary>
/// There are three types of functions that can be defined. The first
/// is a function statement. This is a function appearing as a top-level
/// statement (i.e., not nested inside some other statement) in either a
/// script or a function.
///
/// The second is a function expression, which is a function appearing in
/// an expression except for the third type, which is...
///
/// The third type is a function expression where the expression is the
/// top-level expression in an expression statement.
///
/// The three types of functions have different treatment and must be
/// distinquished.
/// </summary>
public const int FUNCTION_STATEMENT = 1;
public const int FUNCTION_EXPRESSION = 2;
public const int FUNCTION_EXPRESSION_STATEMENT = 3;
```

Here is what I'm roughly seeing:

```
<script>
(function(){document.write("The name is Bond, ")})(),
(function(){document.write("James Bond.")})()
</script>
```

Would this qualify as a `FUNCTION_STATEMENT`, `FUNCTION_EXPRESSION`, `FUNCTION_EXPRESSION_STATEMENT`?

### Update

I guess my question is about the role of the comma:

```
// Expression
(function(){ document.write('Expression1<br>'); })();
(function(){ document.write('Expression2<br>'); })();

// Expression
var showAlert=function(){ document.write('Expression3<br>'); };
showAlert();

// Declaration
function doAlert(){ document.write('Declaration<br>'); }
doAlert();

// What about this?
(function(){ document.write('What about'); })(), // <-- Note the comma
(function(){ document.write(' this?<br>'); })();

// And now this? 
var a = ((function(){ return 1; })(), // <-- Again, a comma
(function(){ return 2; })());
document.write("And now this? a = " + a);
```

What are the last two? Expressions or Expression Statements?

Comment: Probably more information than you want is available here: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/

Comment: [This can help you](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know about EcmaScript.NET, but from my understanding all those functions are function expressions. They are part of a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)-invocation, which again is part of a [comma-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) expression - in no way "*top-level*".

I'd say that the third type are function statements where they are not allowed syntactically, like

```
if (false) {
    function doSomething() {…}
}
```

Check out [Kangax' famous article about named function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), where their behaviour across engines is summed up (e.g. Gecko's [function statements](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements)).